# Getting the installer language

Tags: java, install4j

I'm trying to obtain the selected installer language, as i understand it this variable should contain the selected 2 character language code:

context.getCompilerVariable("sys.languageId")

My default language is 'de' and during the install i select 'en' under the install4j language selection screen, despite this the 'sys.languageId' value is always 'de'.

Is there another variable that can be used?

Comment: @DevilsHnd-退した I'm not sure you read the question, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler variables are fixed at compile time. The compiler variable `sys.languageID` contains the ISO 639 code of the principal language of the project. The code for the language that is actually used by the installer is contained in an **installer** variable of the same name. You can access the value of that variable in text fields with the syntax

```
${installer:sys.languageId}
```

Comment: Thanks as usual Ingo, that did the trick nicely.